# ¿Por qué Python une dos String Literals sin operadores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

¿Por qué python une dos `String` sin ningún tipo de operador como por ejemplo la suma?

Esto:

```
>>> 'Perro' 'Lobo'
'PerroLobo'
```

Hace lo mismo que esto:

```
>>> 'Perro' + 'Lobo'
    'PerroLobo'
```

Comment: Python tiene un manejo muy particular de los string, tiene innumerables particularidades en el diseño de la programación, por ejemplo si multiplicas una string, 'Perro''lobo'*11, es 11 veces esto. La pregunta para mi sería que forma es la mas optima para un lenguaje de programación tan versátil como este.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pues cuando un lenguaje de programación hace algo asi, suele ser por diseño. En este caso, como se explica en la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

> Multiple adjacent string literals (delimited by whitespace), possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their meaning is the same as their concatenation

Traducido:

> Varios literales de cadena (delimitados por un espacio en blanco) adyacentes, posiblemente usando diferentes convenciones de cita (es decir, comillas simples o dobles), están permitidos y su significado es el mismo que el de su concatenación.

Answer (score 2):

Un uso típico que se le da a esta característica es para crear cadenas largas que no te caben en una línea.

Python tiene la posibilidad de usar la "triple comilla" para delimitar cadenas multi-línea, por ejemplo así:

```
texto_largo = """Este es un texto que ocupa
varias líneas y que por tanto he metido
dentro de unas comillas triples."""
```

La cadena resultante contiene también los retornos de carro, como puedes observar si la inspeccionas en el intérprete:

```
>>> texto_largo
'Este es un texto que ocupa\nvarias líneas y que por tanto he metido\ndentro de unas comillas triples.'
```

Puede que no quisieras que los retornos de carro formaran parte de la cadena. Con la triple comilla no tienes forma de evitarlo.

Un problema adicioinal es que la cadena así formateada rompe la indentación del fuente. No es un error para Python, pero dificulta la legibilidad. No digamos ya si la cadena en cuestión aparece dentro de otro bloque que está indentado, como por ejemplo:

```
def ejemplo():
    texto = """Esta cadena
ocupa dos lineas"""
    return texto
```

Esto rompe por completo la legibilidad (aunque python lo admite). Quedaría mucho mejor así:

```
def ejemplo():
    texto = """Esta cadena
               ocupa dos lineas"""
    return texto
```

El problema es que haciendo esto, todos los espacios que hemos usado para indentar la cadena, quedan formando parte de la misma:

```
>>> ejemplo()
'Esta cadena\n               ocupa dos lineas'
```

Vemos entonces que la triple comilla, aunque permite escribir cadenas largas separaándolas en varias líneas en el fuente, plantea dos problemas:

1. Incluye los retornos de carro, cosa que tal vez no queríamos
2. Incluye los espacios al inicio de cada línea, y si no los ponemos la legibilidad disminuye drásticamente.

Para resolver ambos problemas podemos usar este truco:

```
texto_largo = ("Este es un texto que ocupa "
               "varias líneas y que por tanto he metido "
               "en tres cadenas separadas.")
```

El ponerlo entre paréntesis es un truco para que python me permita romper una expresión en varias líneas. Una vez abierto un paréntesis, mientras no se cierre, Python admite retornos de carro y cualquier indentación dentro. Es por tanto equivalente a haber puesto las tres cadenas una al lado de la otra en la misma línea (observa que no he puesto comas tras cada cadena, pues entonces sería una tupla).

Ya que Python las concatenerá en una sola, el resultado es equivalente al ejempo de la triple comilla, sólo que ahora ni los retornos de carro ni los espacios de la indentación forman parte de la cadena.

```
>>> texto_largo
'Este es un texto que ocupa varias líneas y que por tanto he metido en tres cadenas separadas.'
```

Si quisieras que los retornos de carro formaran parte de la cadena resultante, puedes ponerlos manualmente (`"\n"`) dentro de cada trozo:

```
texto_largo = ("Este es un texto que ocupa\n"
               "varias líneas y que por tanto he metido\n"
               "en tres cadenas separadas.")
```